# AWS Lambda deployment error/ Couldn't find module

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

So , I have a python -selenium script which needs to be deployed on AWS Lambda.
It uses multiple external dependencies like selenium, beautiful-soup, fireabase-admin and some apis.
So whenever i install this dependencies , multiple  small other dependencies are also installed like grpcio, urllib3 etc. I have tried various approaches, including separating dependencies into layers, but the problem persists.

Solutions I have tried till now.
**1.** I zipped all my dependencies and my code files in a single zip file and uploaded to Lambda function . This started giving me dependency issues one by one and have tried downgrading/upgrading them successfully. But then it gave me a dependency issue which I wasn't able to solve.

**2.** Then i tried to divide the dependency in a lambda layer and my chromedriver(Also needed to run my script) in another layer . Hence creating 2 layers. I uploaded just me script files to Lambda.
But, Lambda wasn't able to pick my dependencies in this way.
It resulted in  this error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'file_name': No module named 'selenium'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

**Note:** The Lambda function runs successfully on my local environment, but not on AWS Lambda.

I appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully deploy my Python script on AWS Lambda. Thank you!

Solutions I have tried till now.
**1.** Zipping all dependencies and code in a single file

**2.** Dividing dependencies into layers and adding layer to the function.
The zip file structure for my dependency was ->

python.zip -> Lib > python3.8 > site-packages > Rest of dependencies.

I expected the function to run successfully as it does on my Windows local machine but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies with the lambda handler, which must be defined properly in the Lambda function.

The handler should always be in the format "file_name.function_name."

For example, if your Python file is named "lambda_function.py" and your function is called "lambda_handler," as I mentioned below:

[image]

then your handler needs to be like this
[image]